# Git perforce basic integration

Tags: git, perforce

I have looked at questions similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488559/368599. We cannot switch to `git` mainly because our repo size is a few terabytes.

Unfortunately, we cannot use `git-fusion` (not something I can convince the company to use). What I am looking for is more like a band-air solution (scripted library/plugin?) to solve the following problem:

- I start with an empty git repo
- I checkout a bunch of files in P4
- Some sort of a bridge automatically commits *just the checked out files* in the empty repo (or it may not be empty if I have already done these steps)
- Commit to local git repo and have a normal workflow (that I usually have with a git repo)
- I then submit as normal in P4 when done

Nice to have:

- When I am done, I submit my P4 shelf, a git commit is automatically created with the P4 description

I realize there could be a few problems with this approach. But at least it will automate the task of adding the checked out files in a P4 depot.

I have searched for something like this for quite some time without any success. I have lost a lot of hours with the P4 shelving workflow which is extremely rudimentary compared to git local commits.

**NOTE**: Sometimes we cannot submit due to lockdowns. In other cases, the task takes multiple days and cannot be submitted until done. I am forced to use shelves in this case. Incremental edits over several hours/days are simply lost.

Comment: Have you looked at `git-p4`?

Comment: I have. The issue with git-p4 is that it requires a clone of the depot. Our depot is a few terabytes in size and that option in not viable.

Comment: `git-p4` allows you to limit the scope to cloning the files just in a Perforce client spec's view, not the entire depot.

Comment: Okay that definitely piques my interest. I'll look into it a bit more, thanks!